# Creating Spotify playlist with standalone web app

Tags: spotify

I just want to be able to create a playlist by sending / receiving http requests ( a standalone web app, not with Spotify Apps and the desktop client). I've dug around the docs and can't find a clear solution. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to be able to create a playlist by sending / receiving
>   http requests

This isn't possible at the moment — Spotify doesn't have a web API for manipulating playlists. You may be able to hack a solution together using libSpotify, although using libSpotify in a server service this way is against the ToS.

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I was looking for.. But an answer none the less :)

Answer (score 11):

You can pass a list of songs—not a playlist—to the desktop player by adding the track ids to a link as below

```
<a href="spotify:trackset:PlaylistName:49MsPNQCOmxvIYi9AdoPzY,6fUlrsHaz4QfCNF31rk2dU,5KiTsR2h8jnzkvTeucxoAn,6kidUwWb8tB9ktfy7U76iX,6mlUEdb90RqwUisnp65lG7,6KOEK6SeCEZOQkLj5M1PxH,3psrcZoGRaWh6FMGael1NX,3EHLii6bnZxJxsCfLlIb83,0xJtHBdhpdLuClaSQYddI4,6fsdOFwa9lTG7WKL9sEWRU">Play</a>
```

**UPDATE**

As of today there is an api for creating playlists: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/create-playlist/

Comment: That kind of link would be awesome if it worked! Unfortunately, a message says this link is not supported on Spotify for the iPhone, and it makes Spotify crash on my Mac...

Comment: Fuzzy Wuzzy was a bear, Fuzzy Wuzzy should've had no hair!!! Wacka wacka wacka,,,,, gotta fuzzy tacka!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at https://github.com/liesen/spotify-api-server
It is limited to just one spotify account (the one you configure it with) but does allow playlist creation/manipulation via RESTish calls.