# Spotify trackset link on iPhone

Tags: spotify

I have put together a web app that creates a list of tracks that can be played in Spotify using a `spotify:trackset` link, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12218041/51034.

When following the link on my iPhone, it switches to the Spotify app, but then I get an error claiming that it can't open this type of link on the device.

Is there any other way to link to a set of tracks on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spotify iOS client doesn't support tracksets at the moment — the only way to get a list of tracks into the client is via a playlist.