# Can I develop a customized Spotify playlist?

Tags: spotify, playlist

The "MVP" of my app idea would be a simple way to "stick" two or more songs together in a playlist. Basically if I find two songs that go great back to back, I would like to keep them together as I move them throughout my playlist.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Spotify playlist with standalone web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826217/creating-spotify-playlist-with-standalone-web-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've got two toplevel options

1. Develop your own playlist functionality - store a list of songs, manage their order, play the next one when a song completes
2. Work with actual spotify playlists

Option 2 is generally better, as the user will be able to leave your app and still listen to songs.

In the case of option 2, you'd need to register for the Playlist's changed event, scan for the location of Song A, and move Song B after it.  I don't think there is currently a way for it to be super efficient.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the feedback that I hoped for. I'll follow up if I actually build something!